# Hide or remove the submit button on a Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

I've built a Cognito Form to perform a calculation - it will automatically appear when all fields have been completed.

Therefore, the submit button is obsolete - originally I wanted to hide it or remove it completely, but as I believe that's not possible I wanted to set it as a "reset" button that would reload the page.

However, as I am embedding the form in an iFrame HTML box (on a Wix created site) when I press reset it reloads the page in the iFrame HTML box rather than in the main browser window.

Can I hide the submit button, or find a way to have the form redirect/reload the main browser window and not just the iframe it's in?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use a form, but not display a `Submit` button.  The easy way to do this would be to edit your site, and update your HTML box to include the following code above your form embed code:

`<style>#c-submit-button { display:none; }</style>`

This will prevent users from seeing (and thereby pressing) the submit button.

*Disclaimer: I am an engineer on the Cognito Forms team*